# Dimension of linear subspace of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $F$ be a linear subspace of $L^{2}$ with $1\in F$. Consider $$N:=\sup\{\text{dim}V:\text{V is a subspace of F}:q(u)\leq 0~ \forall u\in V\backslash \{0\}\},$$ where $q$ is a quadratic form on $L^{2}$ and we can assume that $\dim V<\infty$. Suppose it holds that for $u\in F$ $$q(u)\leq 0~\text{and}~u\perp 1~\text{imply}~u=0,$$ then why does it hold that $N\leq 1$? If i assume that $1\in V$, we get that $$V=\{1\}+\{1\}^{\perp}=\{1\}+\{0\},$$ whence $N=1$, but what if $1\notin V$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $1$ supposed to be?

Comment: I edited the text

Comment: $\overline{V} = \text{Lin}\{1\}\oplus \{1\}^{+_{\overline{V}}} = \text{Lin}\{1\}$ ($V$ doesn't have to be a Hilbert space a priori)

Comment: Not even if it is finite-dimensional?

Comment: It's fine if it's finite dimensional, because then the subspace is closed.

Comment: Yes I assume that it is indeed finite-dimensional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for arbitrary case. Fix subspace $V$. Assume that $\vec{x},\ \vec{y}\in V$ are linearly independent. Then $(\vec{x}|1)\neq 0$ and $(\vec{y}|1)\neq 0$, so there exist non-zero constants $\alpha, \ \beta$ such that $$\alpha(\vec{x}|1)+\beta(\vec{y}|1) = 0 \implies (\alpha\vec{x}+\beta\vec{y}|1)= 0\implies \alpha\vec{x}+\beta\vec{y} = 0.$$ This is a contradiction since linear independence implies $\alpha = \beta = 0$. Hence $\dim V \leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you, but why is $(x,1)\ne0$?

Comment: If it was $(\vec{x}|1) = 0$, then since $q(\vec{x})\leq 0$ ($\vec{x}\in V$), we would have $\vec{x} = 0$. But then $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ wouldn't be linearly independent.

Comment: How does $q(x)\leq 0$ imply $x=0$ in that case?

Comment: As you said before, $q(\vec{x}) = 0$ and $(\vec{x}|1) = 0$ together imply $\vec{x}= 0$.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you very much!